# Не видит драйвер QPSQL на другой машине Qt

Tags: qt, postgresql

Собрал релиз версию программы, которая работает с postgresql через qt-шный драйвер. Перенес туда все необходимые dll-ки, перенес папку plugins с драйвером. Экзешник запускается, драйвер видит, все замечательно. Но, когда переношу на другую машину драйвер qpsql не распознается. Я не уверен, но может быть на другую машину тоже нужно ставить клиент postgresql? Подскажите, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

UPD:

В корне у меня находятся постгресовские dll:
libeay32.dll
libintl.dll
libpq.dll
ssleay.dll

DependencyWalker просит для самого драйвера:

```
LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL
LIBPQ.DLL
LIBSTDC++-6.DLL
QT5CORE.DLL
QT5SQL.DLL
```

Но это, вероятно, нормально потому что он находится в \plugins, а то что он просит есть в корне.

dll постгреса просят следующее:

```
MSVCR120.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

Вероятно, msvcr120 - это и есть vcredist. Но, я поставил vcredistx86 и это не помогло. Компилил mingw32.

Comment: @kff, спасибо! но, вы уверены на счёт pq.dll ? у меня такой библиотеки в директории постгреса нету...

Comment: @kff, хм, но libpq.dll у меня есть в папке программы, как  и другие библиотеки из папки \postgres\bin

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, клиент PostgreSQL ставить не нужно. Нужны 3 dll-библиотеки из комплекта PostgreSQL: `libintl8.dll`, `libpq.dll`, `lib(забыл)-2.dll` (это приблизительные названия, могу ошибаться, сейчас с собой нет Postgres). Располагаться они должны рядом с основным исполняемым файлом. Кроме того, Postgres скомпилирован в Visual Studio, поэтому вам понадобится установить `vcredist`. Необходимую версию можно узнать с помощью DependencyWalker. А также соблюдайте разрядность. Она должна быть одинаковая у вашей программы, у `vcredist`, у библиотек Postgres.

Драйвер базы данных необходимо поместить в папку sqldrivers. Причем, чтобы всё заработало, мне пришлось самому компилировать этот драйвер. Но раз у вас на основной машине всё работает, то, скорее всего, это не понадобится.

Если не найдёте, точные названия могу написать завтра.

---

UPD. Судя по названию `MSVCR120.DLL`, требуется `vcredist` версии [2013](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=40784). ieshims.dll - это Internet Explorer. Скорее всего, этот файл будет не нужен. Файлы вроде `Qt5Core.dll`, `Qt5Sql` и др. должны быть рядом с исполняемым файлом, а файл `qsqlpsql.dll` должен быть в папке sqldrivers.

---

UPD. Вот список нужных DLL:

```
libiconv-2.dll
libintl-8.dll
libpq.dll
```

Comment: я обновил пост, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: И что, для установки приложения нужно таскать вместе с ним библиотеки из PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, да, надо.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, vcredist 13 года, то , что было нужно!

Comment: @bronstein87, vcredist - это исполняемая среда для приложений, написанных на C++, скомпилированных в Visual Studio. Там содержатся функции, обеспечивающие работу стандартной библиотеки. В Qt те же функции содержатся в библиотеках, которые вы положили рядом с исполняемым файлом.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    qApp->addLibraryPath("plugins"); // путь к папке с плагинами 
                                     // относительно рабочей папки процесса

    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    // ... все остальное
    return 0;
}
```